# How do I read an excel sheet in python wih the xlsx extenssion?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, numpy

Cell In[1], line 6
excel_file_path = 'Y:\UTCRS\25 Team Member Folders\Kevin Quaye\Cone_defects\new_data\Cone_data\Cone_data.xlsx'
^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

what does this error mean?

I tried changing the file to a csv

Comment: Please [edit] you question to include a [mre] showing how you're reading this file.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, the backslash before the U in the file path is being interpreted as the start of a Unicode escape sequence, which is causing the error. To fix this issue, you can either use forward slashes instead of backslashes in your file path, or you can escape the backslashes by doubling them up.

```
# Using forward slashes
excel_file_path = 'Y:/UTCRS/25 Team Member Folders/Kevin Quaye/Cone_defects/new_data/Cone_data/Cone_data.xlsx'

# Escaping the backslashes
excel_file_path = 'Y:\\UTCRS\\25 Team Member Folders\\Kevin Quaye\\Cone_defects\\new_data\\Cone_data\\Cone_data.xlsx'
```

Either of these solutions should resolve the error and allow you to specify the file path correctly.

Comment: Although this is correct, duplicate questions should not be answered in favor of closing them as duplicate.